# dissect a string (removing portions) with Esper syntax

Tags: arrays, string, esper, nesper

I'm using an esper statement to compare to variables and trigger when variable1 != variable2.

My issue is that variable1 contains additional information I don't care about. I just want to match the first portion

Example Data:
Variable1 = testdata.bad.info
Variable2 = testdata

I don't want the following statement to match:
variable1 != variable2

Ideally, I'd like for the statement to remove everything after the decimal on Variable1. If that were the case, the statement would evaluate it like:

Variable1 = testdata
Variable2 = testdata

Any idea how I could achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do "select * from MyEvent(field.startsWith(field2))".
All Java language methods are available in EPL. Otherwise make a callout to a user defined function i.e. "select * from MyEvent(compareMe(field, field2))". Or to use a script as part of EPL.